# RecyclerView for group chat activity not showing up in FirebaseUI within Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, overriding, chat

I'm trying to create a chat messaging tool in Android, upon following a few tutorials, the code is not working.

I've tried changing how the database is read, how its laid out.

I followed this tutorial from here https://medium.com/android-grid/how-to-use-firebaserecycleradpater-with-latest-firebase-dependencies-in-android-aff7a33adb8b

````
public class Chat extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView listOfMessages;
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter adapter;
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<ChatMessage> options;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                EditText input = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input);

                DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Chat").push();
                //add messageText, messageTime, messageUser as a hash map to the database
                Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                map.put("Body", input.getText().toString());
                map.put("Username", FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail());
                map.put("Post time", new Date().getTime());
                reference.setValue(map);
                input.setText("");
            }
        });
        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        listOfMessages.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        listOfMessages.setHasFixedSize(true);
        fetch();
    }

    private void fetch() {
        Log.v("TAG", "in fetch");
        Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Chats");

        Log.v("TAG", query.toString());

        //FirebaseRecyclerAdapter binds query to a RecycleView.  When data is added, removed or changed these updates are automatically applied to UI in real time.
        options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<ChatMessage>()
                .setLifecycleOwner(this)
                .setQuery(query, new SnapshotParser<ChatMessage>(){
                @NonNull
                @Override
                public ChatMessage parseSnapshot(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) { //Needed to customize how ChatMessage class is parsed
                    Log.v("TAG", "in parseSnapshot");
                    return new ChatMessage(snapshot.child("Body").getValue().toString(), snapshot.child("Username").getValue().toString());
                }
            }).build();

        Log.v("TAG", options.toString());

        //Uses a ViewHolder to display each item
        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ChatMessage, ViewHolder>(options) {

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
                //Create a new instance of ViewHolder, uses R.layout.message for each item
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.message, viewGroup, false);
                Log.v("TAG", "in onCreateViewHolder");
                return new ViewHolder(view);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position, ChatMessage model) {
                Log.v("TAG", "in onBindViewHolder");
                holder.setMessageText(model.getMessageText());
                holder.setMessageUser(model.getMessageUser());
            }
        };
        listOfMessages.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public TextView messageText;
        public TextView messageUser;
        public TextView messageTime;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView){
            super(itemView);
            messageText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
            messageUser = itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_user);
            messageTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_time);
        }

        public void setMessageText(String text) {
            messageText.setText(text);
        }

        public void setMessageUser(String user) {
            messageUser.setText(user);
        }

        public void setMessageTime(TextView messageTime) {
            this.messageTime = messageTime;
        }
    }
}
````

The overridden methods should be called, and the log statements written to the console.  However, they do not appear, and the comments don't show up in the Recycle View in the XML.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `startListening()` method for the data to appear.

From the docs:

> The `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` uses an event listener to monitor changes to the Firebase query. To begin listening for data, call the `startListening()` method. You may want to call this in your `onStart()` method. Make sure you have finished any authentication necessary to read the data before calling `startListening()` or your query will fail.

```
  @Override
protected void onStart() {
  super.onStart();
  adapter.startListening();
 }
```

> Similarly, the `stopListening()` call removes the event listener and all data in the adapter. Call this method when the containing Activity or Fragment stops:

```
 @Override
protected void onStop() {
 super.onStop();
 adapter.stopListening();
}
```

Reference:

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md

Comment: Hi,  I actually had tried that in previous attempts, but to no avail.  I tried switching that out to use the `setLifecycleOwner(this)` as well, as that was a common alternative which did not work either.  I also have the database set so that read and writing do not require any authentication for easier testing.

Comment: remove `listOfMessages.setHasFixedSize(true);`

Comment: then there is no hope